# If Paxos algorithm is modified such that the acceptors accept the first value, or the most recent value, does the approach fail?

Tags: algorithm, paxos

I've tried to reason and understand if the algorithm fails in these cases but can't seem to find an example where they would.

If they don't then why isn't any of these followed?

Comment: What do you mean by the most recent value? With the highest ballot?

Comment: Not necessarily the highest. I mean, the most recent value as in the latest value.

Comment: I don't think one can talk about "latest" value in the context of asynchronous systems since you don't have synchronized clocks. Where do you consider your time reference to be?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Don't forget that in later rounds, leaders may be proposing different values than in earlier rounds.  Therefore the first message may have the wrong value.

Furthermore messages may arrive reordered.  (Consider a node that goes offline, then comes back online to find messages coming in random order.)  The most recent message may not be the most recently sent message.

And finally, don't forget that leaders change.  The faster an acceptor can be convinced that it is on the wrong leader, the better.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than asking whether the algorithm fails in such a scenario consider that if each node sees different messages lost, delayed, or reordered, is it correct for a node to just accept the first it happens to recieve? Clearly the answer is no.

The algorithm is designed to work when "first" cannot be decided by looking at the timestamp on a message as clocks on different machines may be out of sync. The algorithm is designed to work when the network paths, distances and congestion, may be different between nodes. Nodes may crash and restart else hang and resume making things even more "hostile".

So a five node cluster could have all two nodes try to be leader and all three see a random ordering of which leaders message is "first". So what's the right answer in that case? The algorithm has a "correct" answer based on its rules which ensures a consistent outcome under all "hostile" comditions.

In summary the point of Paxos is that our logical mental model of "first" as a programmer is based on an assumption of a perfect set of clocks, machines and networks. That doesn't exist in the real world. To try to see if things break if you change the algorithm you need "attack" the message flow with all those things said above. You will likely find some way to "break" things under any change.